# Socialite/apple with laravel 8 and jwt-auth

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-8, laravel-socialite

I'm using jwt-auth last version with socialite package in laravel 8 project.

- JWT-auth is requiring lcobucci/jwt:3.4.5 and they fixed the version to it by its creators because of conflicting problem with laravel 8.
- Socialite/apple is requiring lcobucci/jwt:4.0 to work and it's not being installed on any other version less than lcobucci/jwt:4.0

What should I do to solve this mess?

Comment: Composer update -W

Comment: @maksim did and did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the package to sanctum because of the versions' conflict.

No answer from tymondesign till now.